# Views function: saving a form field value into the profile model attribute

Tags: python, django

I am writing a code for my views function in a django app "colortest" and my Profile model is in django app "users". I want to add a form field data into the Profile Model attribute. When I save the variable I get an IntegrityError

I have searched every site but I can't understand

**colortest/views.py**

```
    from users.models import Profile
def testreport(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        test_result = request.POST.get('test_result')
        p = Profile(user=request.user, test_result=test_result)
        p.save()
        messages.success(request, f'Your account has been Updated!')
        return render(request, 'colortest/test1.html')
    return render(request, 'colortest/result.html')
```

**users/models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=1000, default="")
    test_result = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

I want data to be saved in the test_result field of the Profile Model 
but it keep giving the error

```
IntegrityError at /colortest/result/testreport
UNIQUE constraint failed: users_profile.user_id
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/colortest/result/testreport
Django Version: 2.2.1
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
UNIQUE constraint failed: users_profile.user_id

C:\Users\Osama E.Khan\Desktop\website\colortest\views.py in testreport
        p.save() …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\Osama E.Khan\Desktop\website\users\models.py in save
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to create a new profile for each time the form is saved. Which is this line:

```
p = Profile(user=request.user, test_result=test_result)
```

That will create a new instance of that profile each time. You will need to change that line to check if the profile already exists. After you are re-using an existing profile or creating a new profile it one does not exist you will need to save the latest test result against it or re-model how it is being saved to save a new test result to a profile each time

*Update*

If you want to update to the latest values you can attempt getting the latest value and updating it:

```
def testreport(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        test_result = request.POST.get('test_result')
        try:
            p = request.user.profile
        except Profile.DoesNotExist:
            p = Profile(user=request.user, test_result=test_result)
        p.test_result = test_result
        p.save()
        messages.success(request, f'Your account has been Updated!')
        return render(request, 'colortest/test1.html')
    return render(request, 'colortest/result.html')
```

Comment: I don't want to create a new profile for each form. I want to add the form value to the profile of the User, who's currently logged in

Comment: I added an update above to show how you would save the latest per user entry